# warning thrown with regex

Tags: php, regex

`/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/i` this is my regex but it still is throwing the warning

Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in ...

I believe this is escaped by appending the i at the end, my code for it is this

```
       $emailregex = '/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/i';
   $isbnregex = '/[0-9]{12}[0-9Xx]/i';
   preg_match ($plaintext,$emailregex,$emailaddress);
   var_dump ($emailaddress);
```

can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: btw. the appended `i` doesn't escape anything. It a modifier for case insensitive. In your regex it has no effect, you can remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order of arguments should be :

```
preg_match ($emailregex,$plaintext,$emailaddress);
```

i.e. $emailregex is the first argument

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the parameter order. From the docs:

> ```
> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches
>                                                      [, int $flags = 0
>                                                      [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
> ```

So your code should look like this:

```
preg_match ($emailregex, $plaintext, $emailaddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "i" doesn't escape the regular expression, it asserts that any A-Z literals in the regular expression should match against the target case-insensitively. You need to escape the backslashes in your regular expression like so:

```
$emailregex = '/^\\S+@\S+\\.\\S+$/i';
```

I don't have a machine with PHP on it to hand, but I think that should work. As others have mentioned, the order of your arguments to preg_match are also wrong, but I think the reason you're seeing a warning in your regex is due to the missing escape slashes.